# How get individual values for recursive query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cellphone table where the data as follows,

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

For example iPhone X is made by two different companies so need to output 2. If the model is manufactured by the same company then the count should 1 not 2. If I run the query recursively I get a total count rather than individual count. I'm new to SQL. Could you please correct my query,

`select count(distinct company) from cellphones where model in (select model from cellphones)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple aggregation:

```
select model, count(*) as num_rows,
       count(distinct country) as num_countries
from cellphones 
group by model
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it earlier. The count should be 2 only if the companies are different. If the model is by same company the count should be 1.

Comment: @GowthamM . . . Then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: This answer is correct according to the question. You should accept it.